# Converting Dictionary in list in list to dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am really a newbie. Thanks much.

Dictionary in list from JSON looks like this:

> data1= **[ [**{Code:A, date:XXX}**], [**{Code:B, date:YYY}**]]**

How can i convert this into dataframe?

Output I want is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXnPq.png)

I tried the following code but it's not working.

```
fda_df=pd.read_json(json.dumps(data1))
```

The real data is

> **[**
> **[**
> {
> "code": "AA.US",
> "date": "2022-12-31",
> "earningsEstimateAvg": "4.5400",
> "earningsEstimateGrowth": "0.0630",
> "earningsEstimateHigh": "8.5000",
> "earningsEstimateLow": "2.2000",
> "earningsEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "12.0000",
> "earningsEstimateYearAgoEps": "4.2700",
> "epsRevisionsDownLast30days": "0.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast30days": "6.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast7days": "1.0000",
> "epsTrend30daysAgo": "3.8700",
> "epsTrend60daysAgo": "3.8200",
> "epsTrend7daysAgo": "4.5200",
> "epsTrend90daysAgo": "2.5900",
> "epsTrendCurrent": "4.5400",
> "growth": "0.0630",
> "period": "+1y",
> "revenueEstimateAvg": "11018700000.00",
> "revenueEstimateGrowth": "0.0180",
> "revenueEstimateHigh": "12927000000.00",
> "revenueEstimateLow": "10029900000.00",
> "revenueEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "9.00",
> "revenueEstimateYearAgoEps": null
> **}   ],**
> **[**
> **{**
> **"code": "AAIC.US",**
> "date": "2022-12-31",
> "earningsEstimateAvg": "0.2600",
> "earningsEstimateGrowth": "0.4440",
> "earningsEstimateHigh": "0.3900",
> "earningsEstimateLow": "0.1700",
> "earningsEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "3.0000",
> "earningsEstimateYearAgoEps": "0.1800",
> "epsRevisionsDownLast30days": "0.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast30days": "1.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast7days": "0.0000",
> "epsTrend30daysAgo": "0.2600",
> "epsTrend60daysAgo": "0.2100",
> "epsTrend7daysAgo": "0.2600",
> "epsTrend90daysAgo": "0.2300",
> "epsTrendCurrent": "0.2600",
> "growth": "0.4440",
> "period": "+1y",
> "revenueEstimateAvg": "17280000.00",
> "revenueEstimateGrowth": "0.1680",
> "revenueEstimateHigh": "22110000.00",
> "revenueEstimateLow": "12450000.00",
> "revenueEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "2.00",
> "revenueEstimateYearAgoEps": null
> },
> {
> "code": "AAIC.US",
> "date": "2020-09-30",
> "earningsEstimateAvg": "0.0200",
> "earningsEstimateGrowth": "-0.8890",
> "earningsEstimateHigh": "0.0300",
> "earningsEstimateLow": "0.0200",
> "earningsEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "4.0000",
> "earningsEstimateYearAgoEps": "0.1800",
> "epsRevisionsDownLast30days": "1.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast30days": "2.0000",
> "epsRevisionsUpLast7days": "1.0000",
> "epsTrend30daysAgo": "0.0300",
> "epsTrend60daysAgo": "0.0300",
> "epsTrend7daysAgo": "0.0300",
> "epsTrend90daysAgo": "0.0600",
> "epsTrendCurrent": "0.0200",
> "growth": "-0.8890",
> "period": "0q",
> "revenueEstimateAvg": "3890000.00",
> "revenueEstimateGrowth": "-0.1710",
> "revenueEstimateHigh": "4110000.00",
> "revenueEstimateLow": "3780000.00",
> "revenueEstimateNumberOfAnalysts": "3.00",
> "revenueEstimateYearAgoEps": null
> }
> **] ]**

Comment: I would recommend describing what exactly goes wrong with the code you have above. Also, there is no need of posting the exact data, just a minimal version of it would be sufficient.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: What's with the weird wacky bold square brackets? It's probably better and clearer for everyone if you post just the code as just code.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data1)` might be what you are looking for

have a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### I have done for a sample data. This is what you need

```
import pandas as pd
data= [[{'Code': 'A', 'date':'XXX', 'name' : 'anil', 'age': 15}], [{'Code':'B', 'date':'YYY', 'name': 'kapoor', 'age': 18}]]

col_name = list(data[0][0].keys())
row_data = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    row_data.append(list(data[i][0].values()))

df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns =col_name)
print(df)
```